# How can I pass a SQL to Cursor which is coming as string in DB2?

Tags: db2, cursor, prepared-statement

I want to pass a SQL to my stored proc as input as a string and my stored proc will pass this SQL as a string to a cursor and provide the output. But a Cursor doesn't accept a SQL as string and we need to prepare the SQL statement and then pass it onto the Cursor. I am not able to make that part working. Please find my sample code here :

```
Create Procedure abc(IN stmt VARCHAR(500))
SPECIFIC abc
LANGUAGE SQL
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1

Re: BEGIN
DECLARE Instmt VARCHAR(500)

PREPARE Instmt FROM stmt;
EXECUTE Instmt;
DECLARE v_cur CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR Instmt;

OPEN v_cur;
END Re

--call abc('select ename,sal from emp')
```

It gives me error as such that Cursor is expecting a SQL statement. So more or less I am not able to PREPARE the SQL properly to feed it to the CURSOR.
Error Message:
SQL0104N "An expected token "" was found following "".Expected token may include: ""

Please let me know how I could get it working.

Comment: What is the error? Which Db2 platform and version?

Comment: I have just edited it with the error. It says that Cursor is expecting a SQL statement. So more or less I am not able to PREPARE the SQL properly to feed it to the cursor. I am working in DB2 11.

Comment: I don't see any Db2 error message and code in your question. Add all required information to the question. Which Db2 platform (LUW, z/OS, midrange, ...)?

Comment: Error msg added but not sure about DB2 platform :(.. SQL0104N "An expected token "<cursor declaration>" was found following "".Expected token may include: "<SQL Statement>"

Comment: `declare` statements in Db2 SQL PL have very specific positions inside compound statements; please check the manual for your Db2 version for the correct compound statement syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @

    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE TEST_PROC(IN stmt VARCHAR(500))
    SPECIFIC TEST_PROC
    LANGUAGE SQL
    DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
    BEGIN
    
        DECLARE test_cur CURSOR WITH RETURN TO CALLER FOR test_stmt;
        PREPARE test_stmt FROM stmt;
        OPEN test_cur;
    
    END@
```

Comment: Understand the ORDER of statements in a procedure is enforced, see documentation. Ensure you configure the block delimiter ( for example @) as distinct from the statement delimiter. The way you do this depends on the tool you use to submit the SQL. Also ensure the input statement is sanitized to prevent SQL injections.